# Schubert Cells and Euler Classes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

So i was wondering about the following question:

Suppose we have the tautological bundle $\tau$ over the Grassmanian $Gr(n,N)$ (over $\mathbb{C}$) then we may consider the natural quotient of the trivial bundle by $\tau$ denoted $\mathbb{C}^N/\tau$.

There is a correspondence between closures of Schubert cells and Chern classes (result of Giambelli's formula), furthermore the top dimensional Chern class corresponds to the Euler class. I am interested in finding which Schubert cycle (closure of Schubert cell) the Euler class corresponds to.

My attempt so far:

Since the rank of the quotient bundle is N-n, we have the following correspondence: $e(\mathbb{C}^N/\tau)=c_{N_n}(\mathbb{C}^N/\tau)=c_{N-n}(-\tau)$ so it is sufficient to consider the dual to the tautological bundle $\tau^*$ over $Gr(N-n,M)$ for $M>N-n$, and find the Poincare dual to the zero locus of a section intersecting the zero section transversally.

To do this consider $x_N=0$ then for suitable $V\in Gr(n,N)$ we have $V\subset Ann(x_N)\subset F_{N-1}$ where $F_{n-1}$ is part of the flag $\{0\}=F_0\subset F_1\subset ...\subset F_{N-1}\subset F_N=\mathbb{C}^N$ and $dim(F_i)=i$. Then $dim(V\cap F_{N-1})=N-1$ and further $dim(V\cap F_{n-i})\geq n-i+1$. From here I got that the corresponding Schubert cycle has associated Young diagram a column of height $N-n$. So in conclusion by Giambelli's formula the Schubert cycle Poincare dual to is the transpose of the column, which is just a horizontal row of length $N-n$ i.e. $\sigma=(N-n,0,0,...0)$.

I just wanted to check wether this was indeed the case and wether there are any alternative methods to get the answer - for example is it possible to directly consider a section of the quotient bundle $\mathbb{C}^N/\tau$ (i avoided this method because i was slightly confused as to how we pick a suitable section here i think it should be something like $s(V)=\pi_V:\mathbb{C}^N\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^N/V$ but i am not sure how to get the corresponding cycle- so if someone has a good explanation for this i would be happy to hear it).